# Does the dc.js script support E-commerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

We are trying to enable e-commerce tracking on our website.

Our current GA tracking code is modified to support display advertising, so the initial ga.js script was replaced by 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js'.

Could that be an issue for the e-commerce tracking?

Does the DoubleClick GA integration support e-commerce tracking?

Thanks

Comment: Since it is not possible to give a meaningful answer longer than a word ("yes") I'd vote to close this. If you have encountered a problem with the dc.js integration I suggest you rephrase the question.